# Assume $\{x\}$ is transitive. What can you say about $x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Definition.** A set $X$ is *transitive* if every element of $X$ is a subset of $X$.

Assume $\{x\}$ is *transitive*. What can you say about $x$?

I think, $x$ is the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: You should ask yourself: how many elements does $\{x\}$ have?

Comment: @EricWofsey x should be $\mathbb{N}$ since every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is a subtset of $\mathbb{N}$. For example, define 1={0}, 2={0,1}. Hence, {0}$\subseteq$ {0,1}.

Comment: Hint: how many elements can $x$ have, if $x$ is a subset of $\{x\}$ (or of $\{a\}$, for what it matters...)? It seems we can safely assume that $\aleph_0$ are a  bit too many...

Comment: @Snow one element.

Comment: Correct. However, when you say $\{x\}$ is $\mathbb N$, you are only providing an example of a transitive set. In fact, *any* ordinal number is a transitive set. The question asks which transitive sets can be written as $\{x\}$. Between @G.Sassatelli's hint and mine, you should be able to figure out what $\{x\}$ is.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The set $\{x\}$ is transitive if and only if each element of $\{x\}$ is a subset of $\{x\}$. The only element of $\{x\}$ is $x$, so if $\{x\}$ is transitive, then $x\subseteq\{x\}$. This means that if $y\in x$, then $y\in\{x\}$.

- If there is a $y\in x$, what must it be equal to? This makes $x$ a very strange set; why?
- If there is no $y\in x$, what is $x$? Is $\{x\}$ transitive in this case?